# is there an efficient way of transfering all the rows of one table to another table, one record at a time

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, triggers, foreach

requirement is to transfer all inserted records to one table to another. i've used a trigger to do it. i'm looping through all the inserted records and inserting to new table one record at a time as i have to increment a sequence number in the destination table. but this loop considarably slow when number of inserted rows increase. is there a better way of doing this.

```
Declare @maxpk int, @count int, @seq int
set @maxpk=(select max(refno) from inserted )
set @count=(select count(1) from inserted)
set @seq=((select max(seq_no) from dbase.dbo.destination))

while @count>0
begin
set @seq=(select @seq+1)
insert into dbase.dbo.destination(orderno,SEQ_NO,PRODUCT_ID,qty)
select  ordernumber,@seq,productid ,quantity
from inserted where refno=@maxpk
set @count=(select @count-1)
set @maxpk=(select top 1 refno from inserted where refno<@maxpk)
end
```

refno is primary key of source table. is there a way to check the end of inserted records  so i don't have to initialize and maintain a loop counter?

and can loop be executed for each record in inserted table so i don't have to find the next record to insert by comparing the value of primary key.
 using mssql 2005

Comment: Why isn't `seq_no` an `IDENTITY` column? Also did you know that your `TOP` without `ORDER BY` means SQL Server can pick any row, meaning you could skip rows?

Comment: Great question.  If it can't be, you could create your own temp table with an Identity column initialzed to one over the max seq_no, and then insert from inserted into that, and then insert from the temp table into destination.

Comment: But @GilM that does not handle the case where two users run an insert at the same time.

Comment: table design cannot be altered.because they are used by applications.

Comment: And how do those other applications generate the new `seq_no` values?

Comment: those applications don't have to handle instances where more than one record being inserted at once. they handle only single row operations.

Comment: But they still have to determine the next `seq_no` value, and don't they have to deal with cases where two people can try to insert a single row at the same time? How do you handle that currently?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you're right.  I like your solution below (both the locking hint and the single non-cursor insert).  I think you're also right that the destination table screams for an IDENTITY column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should handle concurrency ok but I really think you need to revisit the design (e.g. make `seq_no` an `IDENTITY` column, then the system generates the unique values for you, and handles concurrency too).

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SourceTrg ON dbo.Source
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @seq INT;
    SET @seq = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(seq_no) 
      FROM dbase.dbo.Destination WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)), 0);

    INSERT dbase.dbo.Destination(SEQ_NO, orderno, PRODUCT_ID, qty)
      SELECT @seq + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY refno),
        ordernumber, productid, quantity
      FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Comment: table design cannot be altered.because they are used by other applications.